# Tomcat Mapper class not found

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I am creating a web app and at the moment I'm trying to get a tomcat server to run. However I get this error message when ran from the cmd line.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/uti
   l/http/mapper/Mapper
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.<init>(StandardContext.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:207)
    at hello.Server.createTomcatServer(Server.java:34)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:57)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.
Mapper

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

This is my pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org     /2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-relational-data-access</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC4</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> 
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.3.2</version> 
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>          
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <!-- put your configurations here -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And finally my tomcat server code:

```
  public void createTomcatServer() throws ServletException, LifecycleException{

    Tomcat tomcat = null;
    Integer webPort = new Integer(9696);

    tomcat.setPort(webPort);

    tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" +    webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

I thought I had included all the correct dependencies, etc. But I just cant find out why its not working - I've looked all over google already - so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you launch your program? Have you included all of the necessary libraries in the class path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem as well and solved it by depending on the embed module instead.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
  <version>${embedded.tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Interestingly, this is the only correct way to solve the issue at hand. The thing is, if you include this, your app will always package a self-contained instance of Tomcat (which is probably not the way you want to go if you're packaging a WAR to deploy into a running Tomcat instance). So make sure you use a non-embedded version as a runtime-dependency when you're about to deploy into a WAR-aware server. Good answer though, fixed the issue on my side!